A way to indicate Latex it can break lines in inline formulae after commas?
I often use long inline math formulae that contains tuples, such as $(\Operator1, \Operator2, \Operator3, \Operator4, ...)$, and also lists of operators such that $\Operator1, \Operator2, \Operator3, \Operator4,... $.
These inline math formulae are often too long and out pass the margin.
I would thus like to know if there is a way to indicate to Latex it can create a newline just after any of the commas of the formulae?
Ideally, through a command, such as:
$\AllowBreakOnCommas{\Operator1, \Operator2, ...}$.

My actual, ugly solution, is to separate it in multiple inline formulae, as in:
$\Operator1,$$ \Operator2,$$ ...$

Thanks for your help!

An MWE we can use to test ideas would be really useful here.

I don't think it's a good idea to allow line breaks while in inline math mode after all instances of , (comma). For instance, if commas are used as decimal markers, it would be most unfortunate to allow a line break at a decimal marker. Instead, I'd issue \allowbreak directives after the math mode commas that are associated with bad line breaks -- and be willing to re-write the sentence at times.

Can you give a real use case?

It is actually a real use case. I use construction that are defined of tuple of algorithms and so I need to write this long list of algorithms with commas: the only change is that the algorithms are not name Operator1, ... .  There is no other commas in these formular except the ones that separate words.

A quick and dirty implementation. Just read in the argument to \AllowBreakOnCommas and replace all the commas with ,\allowbreak (note that commas inside of a nested {} are not handled, so \AllowBreakOnCommas{a{,}b} has no break points):
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \AllowBreakOnCommas { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { , } { , \allowbreak }
    \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Some text and then inline math $(Operator1, Operator2, Operator3, Operator4,
Operator5, Operator6, Operator7, Operator8, Operator9)$

Some text and then inline math $\AllowBreakOnCommas{(Operator1, Operator2,
Operator3, Operator4, Operator5, Operator6, Operator7, Operator8, Operator9)}$
\end{document}


Is there a way to disallow line breaking if a comma functions as a decimal marker -- as in, e.g., $123,456$? (The icomma package or an equivalent may need to be loaded.)

@Mico for any number formatting with decimals I'd most likely use siunitx anyway for which the code here doesn't make any difference. Also, the easiest way to specify a comma that's a decimal comma is $123{,}456$ for which the code doesn't fire anyway.

You also need some additional space to get justification right.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\longlist}{O{}m}
 {% #1 = options, #2 = list
  \egreg_longlist:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__egreg_longlist_items_seq
\tl_new:N \l__egreg_longlist_last_tl

\keys_define:nn { egreg/longlist }
 {
  l .int_set:N = \l__egreg_longlist_left_int,
  l .initial:n = 2,
  r .int_set:N = \l__egreg_longlist_right_int,
  r .initial:n = 2,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_longlist:nn
 {% #1 = options
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { egreg/longlist } {#1}
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__egreg_longlist_items_seq {#2}
  \int_set:Nn \l__egreg_longlist_right_int
   {
    \seq_count:N \l__egreg_longlist_items_seq - \l__egreg_longlist_right_int
   }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__egreg_longlist_items_seq \l__egreg_longlist_last_tl
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__egreg_longlist_items_seq
   {
    ##2,\mspace{0mu plus 3mu}
    \bool_lazy_and:nnT
     { \int_compare_p:n { ##1 >= \l__egreg_longlist_left_int } }
       % we're after the left minimum
     { \int_compare_p:n { ##1 <= \l__egreg_longlist_right_int } }
       % we're before the right minimum
     { \allowbreak }
   }
   \l__egreg_longlist_last_tl
   \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$(\longlist{aaaa, bbb, ccc, dddddddd, eee, fff, gg, hh, iiii, jjj, kkk,
lll, mmm, nnn, oo, ppp, qqq, rrrrrrr, sss, ttt})$

$(\longlist{aaaa, bbb, ccc, dddddddd, eee, fff, gg, hh, iiii, jjj, kkk,
lll, mmm, nnn, oo, ppp})$

$(\longlist[r=1]{aaaa, bbb, ccc, dddddddd, eee, fff, gg, hh, iiii, jjj, kkk,
lll, mmm, nnn, oo, ppp})$

Some dummy text that will push the list to start quite close to the end
$(\longlist{aa, bbb, ccc, dddddddd, eee, fff, gg, hh, iiii, jjj, kkk,
lll, mmm, nnn, oo, ppp, qqq, rrrrrrr, sss, ttt})$

Some dummy text that will push the list to start quite close to the end
$(\longlist[l=1]{aa, bbb, ccc, dddddddd, eee, fff, gg, hh, iiii, jjj, kkk,
lll, mmm, nnn, oo, ppp, qqq, rrrrrrr, sss, ttt})$

\end{document}

The default is two items both at the left and at the right, but you can specify that just one is allowed (or maybe increase these minima).
In the second case, you may judge that the line is too stretched and reduce the right minimum to one, like in the third case.
In the fourth case, the text might be deemed too stretched out, so the left minimum is reduced to one (fifth case).


Thank you and @skillmon for this solution !
